# User access while not defined in Security section?

Tags: sql-server, security, ssms

Sorry if sounds simple or stupid to ask, however,
I have a scenario that a user can log into SQL server instance SSMS 18.9.2 using Windows credentials and query into databases and tables while I see no record of that user into Security folder/section/dB of same instance of SQL server.

Could someone be kind and tell me how this is even possible?

thanks,

I looked over all available Security accounts, individuals and groups and found no relation to that  user at all.

Comment: Were you able to identify which user is used/logged in by sp_who or different methods of accessing active sessions/queries?
Is this user also listed nowhere?

Comment: Or is the ad-account member of a ad-group which is allowed to connect to the sql server?

Comment: Run [xp_logininfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql) to see the ad group(s) for the user that provide SQL access: `EXEC xp_logininfo 'YourDomaain\YourUser', 'all';`

Comment: thanks @DanGuzman xp_logininfo did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a scenario that a user can log into SQL server instance SSMS
> 18.9.2 using Windows credentials and query into databases and tables while I see no record of that user into Security folder/section/dB of
> same instance of SQL server.

A Windows authenticated account can access the SQL instance without a individual account login if the user is a member of a Windows AD group login with server `CONNECT SQL` permission. Furthermore, the account can access an individual database if the user is a member of a Windows AD group with database `CONNECT` permission. AD groups can be nested (groups within groups) and a user can be a member of multiple groups so it can be tricky to determine if an individual account has access to the instance and corresponding permission path using the SSMS UI.

Run [xp_logininfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logininfo-transact-sql) for the user account to list the AD group memberships (permission path) with `CONNECT SQL` permission. The account will also have access to an individual database if the user has `CONNECT` permission in the database, either directly or via AD group membership.

```
EXEC xp_logininfo 'YourDomaain\YourUser', 'all';
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, xp_logininfo revealed that user has actually access. 
Is there something like max number of accounts to be shown under Security folder? meaning that maybe there were too many users there and SSMS simply could not show me the detail of that individual account from the GUI. just a thought

Comment: I'm not aware of such a limit in SSMS but note the Security folders on Object Explorer will only show accounts granted access directly (`CREATE USER`). Users with indirect access via AD group membership will not be visible in SSMS, AFAIK.